# How to make a Trainer pad inputs in a batch with huggingface-transformers?

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I'm trying to train a model using a Trainer, according to the documentation (https://huggingface.co/transformers/master/main_classes/trainer.html#transformers.Trainer) I can specify a tokenizer:

> tokenizer (PreTrainedTokenizerBase, optional) – The tokenizer used to
> preprocess the data. If provided, will be used to automatically pad
> the inputs the maximum length when batching inputs, and it will be
> saved along the model to make it easier to rerun an interrupted
> training or reuse the fine-tuned model.

So padding should be handled automatically, but when trying to run it I get this error:

> ValueError: Unable to create tensor, you should probably activate
> truncation and/or padding with 'padding=True' 'truncation=True' to
> have batched tensors with the same length.

The tokenizer is created this way:

```
tokenizer = BertTokenizerFast.from_pretrained(pretrained_model)
```

And the Trainer like that:

```
trainer = Trainer(
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=train,
    eval_dataset=dev,
    compute_metrics=compute_metrics
)
```

I've tried putting the `padding` and `truncation` parameters in the tokenizer, in the Trainer, and in the training_args. Nothing does. Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried to see in the model config?
config = AutoConfig.from_pretrained(...)

Comment: Same issue here, have you been able to find a solution?

Answer (score 9):

Look at the columns your tokenizer is returning. You might wanna limit it to only the required columns.

For Example

```
def preprocess_function(examples):
   #function to tokenize the dataset.
   if sentence2_key is None:
       return tokenizer(examples[sentence1_key], truncation=True, padding=True)
   return tokenizer(examples[sentence1_key], examples[sentence2_key], truncation=True, padding=True)


encoded_dataset = dataset.map(preprocess_function, batched=True, load_from_cache_file=False)


#Thing you should do is 

columns_to_return = ['input_ids', 'label', 'attention_mask']
encoded_dataset.set_format(type='torch', columns=columns_to_return)
```

Comment: what is sentence1_key and sentence2_key here?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this problem by adding a datacollator to the trainer.

```
from transformers import DataCollatorForTokenClassification
data_collator = DataCollatorForTokenClassification(tokenizer)
trainer = Trainer(
            model=model,
            args=args,
            train_dataset=...,
            eval_dataset=...,
            compute_metrics=compute_metrics,
            data_collator=data_collator,
            tokenizer=tokenizer,
            optimizers=(optimizer, None),
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved by setting `remove_unused_columns=True` to `TrainingArguments`

```
training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir=f"{model_name}-finetuned-v1",
    overwrite_output_dir=True,
    evaluation_strategy="epoch",
    learning_rate=2e-5,
    weight_decay=0.01,
    per_device_train_batch_size=batch_size,
    per_device_eval_batch_size=batch_size,
    push_to_hub=False,
    fp16=False,
    logging_steps=logging_steps,
    remove_unused_columns=True,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when one of the inputs to the tokenizer is `None`.

My tokenizer takes two texts at the same time (so Bert will add [SEP] between them).